# CNN on tfidf as input

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

I am working on fake news detection using CNN, I am new to ccoding CNNs in keras and tensorflow. I need help regarding creating a CNN that takes input as statements in form of vectors each of length 100 and outputs 0 or 1 depending on its predicted value as false or true.

```
X_train.shape
# 10229, 100

X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=2)
X_train.shape
# 10229,100,1

# actual cnn model here
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Conv1D + global max pooling

from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Input
text_len=100
from keras.models import Model

inp = Input(batch_shape=(None, text_len, 1))
conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(inp)
drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(drop21)
drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop22)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(flat2)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

I will really appreciate if someone could give me a working code for this with a little bit of explaination

Comment: why do you need Conv1D? If you u use tfidf a simple Dense network is ok

Comment: i am assuming that you mean ann by dense netwrok, that is simple layers. But I am working to experiment all types of CNN, you can say some sort of research, I am not worried whether it will serve any useful purpose or not, I want to see results and make comparisons based on a number of factors..

I just wrote tfidf since in my 100 dimension encoding of a statement, I have floats, unlike one hot encoding, in actual it is derived from tfidf and some other similar computations to get 100 dimension vector for each statement. And I am new to these things, any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this dummy example, I use a Conv1D with 2D features. The Conv1D accepts as input sequences in 3D format (n_samples, time_steps, features). If you are using 2D features you have to adapt it to 3D. the normal choice is to consider your features as is expanding simply the temporal dimension (expand_dims on axis 1) there is no reason to assume positional/temporal pattern on tfidf/one-hot features.

When you build your NN you start with 3D dimension and you have to pass in 2D. to pass from to 3D to 2D there are lot of possibilities, the post simple is flattening, with 1 temporal dim a pooling layer is useless. if u are using softmax as last activation layer remember to pass to your dense layer a dimensionality equal to the number of your classes

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

## define variable
n_sample = 10229
text_len = 100

## create dummy data
X_train = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,text_len))
y_train = np.random.randint(0,2, n_sample)

## expand train dimnesion: pass from 2d to 3d
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=1)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)

## create model
inp = Input(shape=(1,text_len))
conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same')(inp)
drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same')(drop21)
drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)
pool2 = Flatten()(drop22) # this is an option to pass from 3d to 2d
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(pool2) # the output dim must be equal to the num of class if u use softmax

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```